# raspberry pi random files show up

Tags: raspberry-pi

I've been using my raspberry pi as a web-server for a while, and I noticed random files showing up in the / directory. I couldn't find anything about it online which will help me resolve this issue. Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Sounds like your server was compromised. Nuke it from orbit, reinstall, and check everything you install for possible security vulnerabilities. Look closely at the user that owns the suspicious files.

Comment: What kind of random files? Images? Text files? config files? temp files?...

Comment: could just be log files, or core dumps..